Replace all values in column after occurrence of specific value
This is probably simple, but I'm missing it. In the example I have several id's with multiple values each. Within each id, I want to be able to set x to equal 0 only after the occurrence of a 2, leaving the other values untouched.
Is there a dplyr way to do this?
test <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
                              3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
                              8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), x = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                              2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                              1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                              1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -46L), class = "data.frame")

> head(test, 10)
   id x
1   1 0
2   1 1
3   1 1
4   1 2
5   1 1
6   2 0
7   2 0
8   2 1
9   2 2
10  2 1


This is the x in your test df the desired output?

No that's what I have - I want to change it so that the potential 1's that follow a 2 for each id are changed to 0 (hopefully that makes sense)

mutate(test, x_new=ifelse(+cumsum(lag(x, default=0)==2), 0, x), .by=id)

   id x x_new
1   1 0     0
2   1 1     1
3   1 1     1
4   1 2     2
5   1 1     0
6   2 0     0
7   2 0     0
8   2 1     1
9   2 2     2
10  2 1     0
11  3 0     0
12  3 0     0
13  3 1     1
14  3 2     2
15  3 1     0


We could also use cummax(): mutate(test, x= ifelse(cummax(x == 2) & x != 2, 0, x), .by = id)

@TarJae Yes, of course. Good point. Simplifies the code a bit. :)

If I understood correctly this is your desired output
library(dplyr)    

head(test,10) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(result = if_else(row_number() > which(x==2),0,x))


      id     x result
   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
 1     1     0      0
 2     1     1      1
 3     1     1      1
 4     1     2      2
 5     1     1      0
 6     2     0      0
 7     2     0      0
 8     2     1      1
 9     2     2      2
10     2     1      0


Thank you - that works based on what I now realise was me not explaining things correctly (sorry!). What I wanted was to set ALL values after the 2, to 0, not just the immediate value.

Try this version

Thanks - if I run it on the full df, I get  "Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: result = if_else(row_number() > which(x == 2), 0, x).
ℹ In group 4: id = 4.
Caused by error in if_else():
! false must have size 0, not size 3."
